# Vue component not detected in Firefox (v73) with vuejs-devtools

Tags: vue.js, vue-devtools

I am using the vuejs devtools with storybook and the components inside it are not detected.

I already accepted the two permissions. The only thing that work is event tracking with all informations related to it.

If someone has an idea, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so currently it only needs to open the `iframe`. There is a specific button on the top-right of the window.
[image: Three buttons on the top-right, pick the one in the middle]

Then it will open the iframe and Vue Devtools can be used normally in this specific window.